# View file stored in database using php on browser

Tags: php, mysql, sql, browser, view

I'm trying to view files (i.e: excel sheets/pdf/images) on browser that are stored in database.

I already wrote a code for downloading the files from the database and it is working but I want to display it in the browser.

Here is the code:

```
<?php require_once('Connections/databasestudents.php'); ?>
<?php 
    $id = $_GET['id']; // ID of entry you wish to view.  To use this enter "view.php?id=x" where x is the entry you wish to view. 

    $query = "SELECT fileContent, filetype FROM file where id = $id"; //Find the file, pull the filecontents and the filetype
    $result = MYSQL_QUERY($query);    // run the query

    if($row=mysql_fetch_row($result)) // pull the first row of the result into an array(there will only be one)
    {
        $data = $row[0];    // First bit is the data
        $type = $row[1];    // second is the filename

        Header( "Content-type: $type"); // Send the header of the approptiate file type, if it's' a image you want it to show as one :)
        print $data; // Send the data.
    }
    else // the id was invalid
    {
        echo "invalid id";
    }
?>
```

What happens is that view.php is downloaded and nothing is viewed.

Any suggestions?

Comment: PHP is either configured incorrectly on your webserver, or not installed.

Comment: all my other php pages do work! And I downloaded wamp sever which installed php,sql and apache automatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your code, `$row[1]` is "the filename". The Content type header should contain the *content type* instead, i.e. the file mime type, for example:

```
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
```

If you want to add a filename:

```
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$row[1]);
print $data;
```

Be sure `$data` is the content of the file, something you can take from [readfile()](http://www.php.net/readfile) for example.

Read more on the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php

Keep in mind that while PDF and images are easily viewable by a browser, I think Excel needs some *ad hoc* plugin for that.

A more complete example *right out of the manual*, to get you a more thorough idea (not all those headers are necessary, and you should change others accordingly to your code):

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));

ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($file);

exit;
```

Comment: thanks.. it doesn't download now, it opens a new page. However, there is an error and lot of strange characters appearing

Comment: That's because something is wrong with how the code is interpreted, you're showing the binary file content. Read more on the linked manual page to get all the headers you need for your specific case